# Delete S3 directories that are in a file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file that has thousands of s3 directories. Each line contains s3 paths, one path per line. Example: `s3://bucket1/folder1/folder2 s3://bucket1/folder2/folder3`. When I select this path and run `aws s3 rm` it executes fine. But, when I use the following command to remove all the s3 directories in `file.txt` it doesn't seem to working and it says access denied with error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied`.

`while LANG=C IFS= read -r in ; do aws s3 rm ${in}; done <file.txt`
Please note that I run a script to generate the credentials to connect to `aws s3` that will be valid for 1 hour. For some reason the credentials don't seem to apply when I run the above command. I could manually execute `aws s3 rm s3://bucket1/folder1/folder2` from command line and remove one path at a time.

I have also tried to execute this with a script file. This script file has one `aws s3 rm` per each line. I have added the following lines at the beginning to make sure that `aws s3 rm` command has the required credentials.

`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCEXAMPLEKEY export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Any thoughts to point me in the right direction?

Comment: what are the exact contents of `file.txt`?

Comment: Does not answer my question and adding *anything* into the file other than s3 paths will certainly break.

Comment: it contains s3 paths, one path per line. Example:

```
s3://bucket1/folder1/folder2
s3://bucket1/folder2/folder3
```

Comment: Okay, then add e.g. a `echo $in` to the inner statement to see what it actually tries to delete.

Comment: @luk2302 - I tried echo to make sure it is deleting the right path. What is printed is what I was able to delete manually.

Comment: I'm no bash expert. But I do wonder- could it have to do with not quoting `${in}`? Could it be getting messed up if one of the lines/paths has a space in it?